# Optimising an implicit self join query

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have the following table `log`. It depicts a series of timestamped events associated with a serial number. There are various event type columns, here just 2 columns are shown - `session_started` and `voltage_changed`. In each row there will only ever be one event type that is non-null. All rows have non-null `serial` and `time_stamp` fields. The first row has both event types set to NULL, meaning that one of the other event type columns (not shown) contains a value (It helps with the representative sample).

I want to find for each `session_started` event that occurs, the very next `voltage_changed` value that is logged (by timestamp). Here is the data:

```
serial ||     time_stamp        || session_started || voltage_changed

BBBB    |  2017-12-15 03:05:55  |        NULL      |        NULL    |
AAAA    |  2017-12-15 04:05:55  |        1         |        NULL    |
AAAA    |  2017-12-15 04:30:55  |        NULL      |        127     |
AAAA    |  2017-12-15 05:15:55  |        NULL      |        75      |
BBBB    |  2017-12-15 05:20:55  |        1         |        NULL    |
BBBB    |  2017-12-15 06:00:55  |        NULL      |        10      |
```

And the desired result:

```
serial ||     time_stamp        ||    voltage

AAAA    |  2017-12-15 04:05:55  |       127        |
BBBB    |  2017-12-15 05:20:55  |       10         |
```

Here is the query I have tried. It works and produces the correct result on this sample table, but takes an extremely long time to run on the full table (I get tired of waiting for the query to finish executing...) The full table has 190,000 rows and has an index on time_stamp.

```
SELECT 
   h.serial, 
   h.time_stamp,
   hh.voltage_changed AS voltage 
FROM 
   log h, 
   log hh 
WHERE 
   h.serial = hh.serial 
   AND hh.time_stamp = (SELECT MIN(hh.time_stamp) 
                        FROM  log hh 
                        WHERE (hh.time_stamp >= h.time_stamp) 
                        AND hh.voltage_changed IS NOT NULL 
                        AND (h.session_started = 1));
```

Is there a way to optimise this query to work more efficiently on a large table? Is having an index on time_stamp sufficient, or should we consider other columns in this instance?

Comment: Your query is confusing, it uses the table alias `hh` twice. It is obvious you have to try to get rid of the sub-select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want only one column, I think the self-join is unnecessary.  I would start by writing this as a correlated subquery:

```
select l.*,
       (select l2.voltage_changed
        from log l2
        where l2.serial = l.serial and
              l2.time_stamp >= l.time_stamp and
              l2.voltage_changed is not null
        order by l2.time_stamp asc
        limit 1
       ) as voltage_changed
from log l
where l.session_started = 1;
```

For this, you want two indexes.  The more important is `log(serial, voltage_changed, time_stamp)`.  The second is `log(session_started, serial)`.

Comment: I added `LIMIT 1` after `asc` to remove a `multiple results on subquery` error, and now it seems to give what I wanted and executes in around 2 minutes. Fetch is taking forever but that's probably me over a VPN :)

Answer (score 1):

I would reshape your data to `serial | time_stamp | event_type | event_value` structure, so that you have `session_started`, `voltage_changed` or other values in `event_type` column, and whatever integer value is associated with the event in the `event_value` column. And index by `event_type` and `serial` with `serial` being a clustered index.

In this case the necessary rows will be filtered efficiently without having to scan the entire table for non-empty values of `voltage_changed` column for further self-join.

Then your query would be something like (works with correlated subquery too):

```
select
t1.serial,
t1.time_stamp,
t2.event_value as voltage
from (
    select
    e1.serial,
    e2.time_stamp,
    min(e3.timestamp) AS voltage_ts
    from log e1
    left join log e2
    on e1.serial=e2.serial
    and e1.time_stamp<=e2.time_stamp
    and e2.event_type='voltage_changed'
    where e1.event_type='session_started'
    and e1.event_value=1
    group by 1,2
) t1
join log t2
on t1.serial=t2.serial
and t1.voltage_ts=t2.time_stamp
and t2.event_type='voltage_changed';
```

I know there might be valid considerations for keeping this data as is, just providing another viewpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately the event values are not all integers, they take many different types. It would be a lot more convenient though :)

Comment: @EkcenierK you can store it as varchar then and cast to integer, that's relatively cheep operation vs. scanning the entire table to get relevant values. A tradeoff might be to continue storing values in different columns but add indexed `event_type` so you preserve correct data types and are able to filter necessary rows efficiently. Also, I'm talking more about OLAP other than OLTP environment here... which one do you have?

Comment: It is indeed OLAP. Thanks for your additional suggestions, they are very helpful and will certainly consider them.